# Not Able to send PDF Attachments with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Hi I am trying to send an Email with a PDF Attachment using sendmail

and also added below line in configuration file to raise delivery errors

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

and here is my code which I written for attachemnt

```
def site_launch(email,name)
    @name = name
    attachments["checkinforgood_manual_deck.pdf"] = File.read(Rails.root.join('public/images/posters/cmanual_deck2.pdf'))
    mail(:from => "info@yopmail.com",
     :to => sent@yopmail.com,
     :subject => 'Make your good Fundraiser amazing.')
end
```

not able to understand what I am doing  wrong here. email is not delivering me and neither raise errror too. but in Log is showing get delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're application is running in development mode. To send mail in actual application must be in production mode.
So, in development mode you'll get log generated, only.
I hope this will explain something.

Comment: I had Configure mailer for development mode as well. and I can send the mail without an Attachment. its just getting not delivered when any attachment is associated with that email. can you tell me is there any size limitation for attachments in rails

Comment: It all depends on the configuration of the mail server. Gmail for example allows messages up to 25M. and while sending attachment, file is translated into binaries. Which increases its overall size while sending attachments. so approx size can be attachment, will be somewhere 16-19mb. Try small file as attachment. Even if faces issue, check you configuration.
And if possible can provide your configuration here. I've configured my app(demo) for your case and i'm able to send mail with attachment also. Performs few checks and let me know.